# Why are some bytes prefixed with 0xf7 when using charset: x-user-defined with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to use XMLHttpRequest to download binary data. When I set the charset to 'x-user-defined' so the browser won't mess with the data, the browser does not set each byte of the response to the low byte of a UTF-16 string; instead, some bytes are prefixed by 0xf7. I am specifically trying to do this in an Android WebView, but I believe Firefox does the same thing.

Why is this happening? I'm getting exactly the data I want, but I have to `&& 0xff` against each byte to strip away the unwanted 0xf7.

Comment: Is it confined to one browser, or does the problem occur on multiple browsers?

Comment: It is standard behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is mentioned in [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Receiving_binary_data), and the explanation comes from Marcus Granado (text no longer available, but read the [backup from web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20071103070418/http://mgran.blogspot.com/2006/08/downloading-binary-streams-with.html)):

> The charset x-user-defined uses the UNICODE Private Area
>   `0xF700`-`0xF7ff` to map its range.

When you do `& 0xff` you simply discard the byte in the high-order position.

Comment: For the bonus round, why doesn't ISO8859-1 do the same thing but with a high byte of 0x00? Overridden by encoding detection?

Comment: The 'x-user-defined' charset is a trick to transfer binary data unprocessed ("Private-use code points are considered to be assigned characters, but they have no interpretation specified by the Unicode standard"). You aren't expected to do binary shifting in standard ISO8859-1.

Comment: "Real" ISO-8859-1 would map bytes to Unicode U+0000-U+00FF, but for compatibility with legacy content `ISO-8859-1` is actually an alias for windows-1252 on the web. See [the Encoding standard](http://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#dfnReturnLink-0).

Answer (score 3):

moraes' answer explains why this happens, but you shouldn't be using `x-user-defined` anymore as most modern (i.e. not IE) browsers, including Firefox stable, support ArrayBuffers now. Do the following instead:

```
// after xhr.open()
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

// after xhr load
var buf =
       xhr.responseBody           // XHR2
    || xhr.response               // FF7/Chrome 11-15
    || xhr.mozResponseArrayBuffer // FF5
;
// buf is an ArrayBuffer
```

Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1138724) for an example of how to get Blobs and ArrayBuffers from XHRs.

Comment: Cool, but I'm on mobile so this doesn't help me yet.

Comment: Always good to point out when new standards are available, but I wouldn't go so far as to say you *shouldn't* be using `x-user-defined`. Sometimes people are forced to support IE for business reasons, they're on mobile, or they just want to write extremely portable code (jQuery didn't become famous for only working on Chrome)